# Finding eigenvectors of a matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\-1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Here is how I find eigenvalues:
$$\begin{align*}
 \det(A - \lambda I) &= \det \Bigg(\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\-1&0&0\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}\lambda&0&0\\0&\lambda&0\\0&0&\lambda \end{bmatrix} \Bigg)\\
&= \det \Bigg(\begin{bmatrix} -\lambda&1&0 \\ 0&-\lambda&1 \\ -1&0&-\lambda \end{bmatrix} \Bigg)\\
&= -\lambda^3 - 1\\
\therefore \lambda =& -1
\end{align*}$$

Using eigenvalue that I found ($-1$), I want to find eigenvectors:
$$\begin{align*}
        (A - \lambda I)\vec{V} =& 0\\
        \Bigg(\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\-1&0&0\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}-1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}\Bigg) \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z \end{bmatrix} =& \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\\
        \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&1\\-1&0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z \end{bmatrix} = & \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\\
        \begin{bmatrix} x+y \\ y+z \\ -x+z \end{bmatrix} = & \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\\
    \end{align*}$$

But what I should do from now? What is really the eigenvectors? Does this means that I have unlimited eigenvectors and any number that satisfies three equations can be eigenvectors?

Comment: There are _at most_ three linear independent eigenvectors (but there could be fewer if one of the eigenvalues is $0$).

Comment: Use $\lambda = -1$ (instead of your current $-\lambda$ along the diagonal of $\lambda I$, substitute $-1$ for each diagonal entry) in the last part to get a system of three variables $x,y,z$ and solve this for the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1$ that you found.

Comment: Good, now solve this to obtain the eigenvector. Solving systems of simultaneous equations is something taught in an elementary algebra course, but you can use linear algebra here and just row-reduce the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Note that there may be more than $1$ solution, but you can find the general eigenvector - in fact, there are since subtracting the second equation from the first equation and adding the result to the third equation yields $0=0$.

Comment: All of the _distinct_ eigenvectors should be orthogonal (i.e. linearly independent).  Where this gets tricky is when you have a multiplicity--especially if you have an eigenvalue of $0$ (but you don't have that in this case).  It's pretty trivial to show that once you have an eigenvector $\vec{v}_1$ that $\alpha \vec{v}_1$ ($\alpha \neq 0$) is _also_ an eigenvector (but those two will _not_ be orthogonal thus they are _not_ distinct eigenvectors).

Comment: Substitute a value for $x$,$y$, or $z$ and find an eigenvector, this works as well.

Comment: @Jared why does an eigenvalue of $0$ make a difference?

Comment: @Callus Actually, I don't think $0$ is "special"--if you have a multiplicity (period whether or not it's a $0$ eigenvalue) then things can become tricky because there may be one or more eigenvectors for the degenerate eigenvalue.  If you have a multiplicity $n$ for $\lambda$ then there could be anywhere from $1$ to $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors for $\lambda$ (i.e. there may _not_ exist $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors).  _Caveat:_ I think there is always _at least_ one eigenvector but that may be incorrect.

Comment: @Jared yeah, I agree.

Comment: @Callus but $\lambda = 0$ is peculiar never-the-less.  It basically means you have $A\vec{v} = \vec{0} = 0*\vec{v}$--of course this is just due to the fact that there are non-trivial solutions to a singular matrix set to $\vec{0}$ (which will have an eigenvalue of $0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your characteristic equation is:

$$
\lambda^3 = -1 \rightarrow \lambda = e^{\pi i + \frac{2n\pi}{3}i}
$$
and gives three distinct eigenvalues, there are *exactly* three eigenvectors only *one* of which has eigenvalue $\lambda = -1$.

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 &1& 1 \\
-1 &0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 &1& 1 \\
0 &1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now the last two are degenerate (as we would expect) which gives:

$$
y = -z \\
x = -y = z \\
(z, -z, z) \rightarrow (1, -1, 1)
$$

So $\left\langle1, -1, 1\right\rangle$ or $\left\langle \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right\rangle$ is the only eigenvector for $\lambda = -1$.

*By only eigenvector, I mean that all eigenvectors for $\lambda = -1$ will be scalar multiples of the above.*

Answer (score 1):

Well, the polynomial $\lambda^3+1$ has two more (*complex*) roots, which means a rotation in a $2$ dimensional subspace.

In your last equation substitute $\lambda=-1$ and, say, $x=1$ to find one eigenvector. 
(You are right: there are infinitely many eigenvectors if there is one as they always form a *subspace*.)

Answer (score 0):

For any scalar $k$, if $v$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda$ ($Av=\lambda v$) then so is $kv$ ($A(kv)=kAv=k\lambda v=\lambda(kv)$).  The last line of your set of matrix equations is the homogeneous system $x+y=0$, $y+z=0$, $-x+z=0$.  This system is not linearly independent, but that's OK.  Doing a bit of solving gives you $x=z$ and $y=-z$, so $(x,y,z)=(z,-z,z)=z(1,-1,1)$.  Yes, you get infinitely many eigenvectors, but they are all scalar multiples of eigenvector $(1,-1,1)$.  This is normal -- you actually get a whole subspace of eigenvectors for any eigenvalue, with the dimension of the subspace corresponding to the multiplicity of the root in the characteristic polynomial.  The vector $(1,-1,1)$ provides a basis for the eigenspace associated with your eigenvalue $\lambda=1$.  (You should also note that, in your example, you also get two complex roots -- if your base field is $\mathbb C$ then you get eigenspaces for those values, too.) [Edit: fixed a typo]

Answer (score 0):

We could put the solution in a cleaner form:

Let $\lambda =-1$ be our eigenvalue. Then we have
$$
\begin{align}
M&=A-\lambda I\\&= \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&1\\-1&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
Let the corresponding eigenvector be $\overrightarrow{v}$:
$$
\overrightarrow{v}=\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix}
$$
such that $M\overrightarrow{v}=\overrightarrow{0},\ \overrightarrow{v}\ne0$. Then we have
$$
v_1+v_2=0\\ v_2+v_3=0\\-v_1+v_3=0
$$
Solving the system of linear equations, we have:
$$
ker(M)=\left\{\;t\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix},\; t\in\mathbb{R}\backslash \left\{0\right\} \right\}
$$
Hence the corresponding eigenvector is 
$$
\overrightarrow{v}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$